# Qemu throws back error after i tried to use whpx acceleration (not sure if this the right community)

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu, hypervisor, windows-11-preview

I am using qemu to emulate Zorin OS 16 (a hour old user of qemu) I tried to emulate Zorin OS 16 with whpx acceleration with this command in power shell:

```
qemu-system-x86_64.exe -boot d -cdrom zorincore.iso -m 8000 -accel whpx
```

...then zorin starts but it throws back this error in powershell:

```
WHPX: setting APIC emulation mode in the hypervisor
Windows Hypervisor Platform accelerator is operational
whpx: injection failed, MSI (0, 0) delivery: 0, dest_mode: 0, trigger mode: 0, vector: 0, lost (c0350005)
```

how to fix the error? " (I am using Windows 11 Preview Build 220000.194 and I enabled Windows Hypervisor Platform Feature)

Comment: I have the same error on Windows 10, so it's not platform specific.